# send a variable to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a checkbox and I want to run a function when it is checked and run another function when its unchecked. My code is:

```
function showCustomer(str,str2) {
    if (document.getElementById(str).checked) {
        var xhttp;
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("xxxx").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("xxxx").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "add.jsp?q=" + str + "&q2=" + str2, true);
    xhttp.send();
    }
    else {
        var xhttp;
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("xxxx").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("xxxx").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "minus.jsp?q=" + str + "&q2=" + str2, true);
    xhttp.send();
    }
}
```

and my checkbox code is:

```
<input id="<%=cheque_tbl.getPRICE()%>" class="ch" type="checkbox" name="<%=cheque_tbl.getCHECKID()%>" onchange="showCustomer(this.value,this.id)">
```

The problem is that `document.getElementById(str).checked` doesn't work and must be `document.getElementById("str").checked` but my checkbox id is not a simple string and is a variable.

How can I use a var in `getelement`? Why doesn't my code work?

Comment: `document.getElementById(yourvariable).checked`?

Comment: Check whether value of str is same as that of value of actual id ? You can check the actual id of checkbox using Developer tools of browser.

Comment: Try this <input id="<%=cheque_tbl.getPRICE()%>" class="ch" type="checkbox" name="<%=cheque_tbl.getCHECKID()%>" onchange='showCustomer("<%=cheque_tbl.getPRICE()%>","<%=cheque_tbl.getCHECKID()%>")'>

Comment: @quardio yes i want my variable.

Comment: try changing your onchange event to be called with checkbox scope like,onchange="showCustomer.apply(this,[this.value,this.id]); then use if(this.checked){...} everywhere to easily access the checkbox

Comment: Does `str` has `elementId` or some string. Coz, `if(str == "")` does not makes sense. Also if you are not using jQuery, remove the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML changes: bind the checkbox scope to access it thrugh 'this'in onchange function

```
<input id="dd" class="ch" type="checkbox" name="dd" onchange="showCustomer.apply(this,[this.value,this.id])">
```

JS change:

```
function showCustomer(str,str2) {
    if (this.checked) {
        var xhttp;
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("xxxx").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("xxxx").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "add.jsp?q=" + str + "&q2=" + str2, true);
    xhttp.send();
    }
    else {
        var xhttp;
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("xxxx").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("xxxx").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "minus.jsp?q=" + str + "&q2=" + str2, true);
    xhttp.send();
    }
}
```

hope it helps to resolve the Document.getElementById() problem for the checkbox

Comment: god man thank u.i have searched whole web in several days.u realy did a great job for me.and my work.

Answer (score 0):

First you are passing `value, id`

```
<input id="<%=cheque_tbl.getPRICE()%>" class="ch" type="checkbox" name="<%=cheque_tbl.getCHECKID()%>" onchange="showCustomer(this.value,this.id)">
```

and you are trying to access using value

```
document.getElementById(str).checked
```

hence, you are not getting element and `element.checked` will be `undefined` or falsey.

Change it as,

```
document.getElementById(str1).checked
```

and it should work.

You can also send element reference as well.

```js
function showCustomer(el) {
  console.log(el.checked, el.value)
}
```

```html
<input 
       id="<%=cheque_tbl.getPRICE()%>" 
       class="ch" 
       type="checkbox" 
       name="<%=cheque_tbl.getCHECKID()%>" 
       onchange="showCustomer(this)">
<!--                          ^^^^                       -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <input id="<%=cheque_tbl.getPRICE()%>" class="ch" type="checkbox" name="<%=cheque_tbl.getCHECKID()%>" onchange="showCustomer(this,this.id)">
```

and in function showCustomer simply use str.checked instead of document.getElementById(str).checked.